# How long can rails keep Ajax open

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, view

My application is suppose to constantly update the page without any user interaction. The criteria is that the page just has to be there, as an extra window on the monitor so the user can see the information get updated real time.

I'm using the Ajax in jQuery with Rails, and my question is - how long will the .erb page keep Ajax open? Will there be a point where I have to refresh the page or re-initialize? Or will that won't be a problem at all?

Comment: what version of rails are you using?  In rails 4, there is the live streaming feature that sounds like it could satisfy your requirement.  [check out this blog post about streaming data](http://rubysnippets.com/2013/04/10/rails-4-live-streaming-versus-node-dot-js/)

Comment: I'm using 3.2. But is my concern something to be aware of?

Comment: so it sounds like you have or need a page that renders the current state of some process.  There are definitely timeouts for rendering a page.  These can vary depending on the application server (unicorn for example) configuration.  If your background page always returns current state, then your ajax call can run in a loop to poll the page every so often and refresh your app page, eliminating the need for an open connection.

Comment: In theory there will be no problem to set an interval that will make an Ajax call to "check for updates" and update the page without any interaction, but if you need something close to real-time updates (like a live chat) , you should consider Rails 4 Streaming feature as @plasticide pointed out OR using Sockets (Socket.io & Node.js for example)

Comment: The place where I'm pulling the data is a dedicated port that does the live stream of data. What I have to do is constantly decode the JSON sent object, if that is of any help.

Comment: rails have websockets?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax means Asynchronous Javascript and XML. What it does is send requests to the server and process it's answers in an asynchronous way; without having to refresh your page.

A request to an HTTP server is not something that keeps open (unless you configure it to maintain connections open and generally that is not the case).
HTTP protocol is stateless, and that means that each request you make to the server will be considered with no connection at all with previous requests. In fact, to maintain a state between requests you got to manage that on the web application level which in this case is rails, sending an identifier of the browser session to the server (usually a session id stored locally on a client web browser cookie) which can be processed by your rails app to identify an open session.

So, unless your frontend is interacting with an HTTP server with persistent connections, your server won't keep the connection established with a web browser open. It will  send it's response and close the connection.

What AJAX allows is to make requests to the server, and process it's responses without reloading the page. The http server will open the connection until it responds to your web browser request, after that the connection is closed, so no continuity will be maintained.

To maintain updated the data on your erb view, you have to manage that with jQuery, sending requests every x amount of time. Bellow is an example that makes an ajax request every 1 second.

```
setInterval( "fetchDataAndUpdateView();", 1000 ); 
fetchDataAndUpdateView = function(){ 
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "your-url",
    success: function(){ 
      //do something here to update your html with the data you got from the server
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: But that has an interval. I need real time.

Comment: @Alexey You should consider using Rails 4 OR a Socket (Socket.io & Node.js for Rails) in this case. Also, guille.mas proposed a solution that will check every seconds, which is not bad, almost real-time.

Comment: Are you talking about a stream? What is the name and version of your server? I had thought you where communicating with an http server like Apache or nginx.

Comment: If you got to implement the server side you should consider (as @MrYoshiji said) a Socket. Socket.io seems to be an interesting option :)

Comment: I was given an IP and a port of our server, saying that it provides constant updates of the information in JSON format. I have to be able to get that information and display in my view as it is updated.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be a socket. Take a look at the link @MrYoshiji gave you. I am looking some very simple examples at socket.io . This is not a job for jQuery.

Comment: I personally used Node.js & Socket.io to create a multiplayer game like farmville (https://github.com/Yoshiji/furry-archer), its was incredible how it is easy to use Socket.io, I strongly recommend this one ;)

Comment: Socket.io seems to allow communication from a webapp frontend to websockets (in fact I do not think that is possible to use AJAX with udp or tcp-non-web sockets because AJAX relies on web browsers object XMLHttpRequest which, as the name said, the object responsible of making HTTP requests to servers, what makes me think that you can only communicate to websockets (sockets that make use of tcp and http protocols) from your webapp frontend. So jQuery is capable of doing that (code.google.com/p/jquery-websocket). You will allways have an interval, but it can be smaller